# Adding Delay In A For Loop Without Blocking UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, delay, delayed-execution

In my UI, when a button is tapped, it calls a for loop that executes several tasks sequentially.

```
// For Loop
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // Perform Task[i]
}
// Results:
// Task 1
// Task 2
// Task 3
```

After each task, I would like add a user-defined delay. For example:

```
// For Loop
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // Perform Task[i]
    // Add Delay Here
}

// Results:
//
// Task 1
// Delay 2.5 seconds
//
// Task 2
// Delay 3 seconds
//
// Task 3
// Delay 2 seconds
```

In iOS, using Objective-C, is there a way to add such delays within a for loop, keeping in mind:

1. The UI should remain responsive.
2. The tasks must be performed in order, sequentially.

A code example within the context of a for loop would be most helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this solution work? Instead of using dispatch_after, I use dispatch_async with a [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval] block, which allows me to put a delay anywhere that I need in my custom queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    NSLog(@“Task1”);
});

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.5];
});

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    NSLog(@“Task2”);
});

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3.0];
});

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    NSLog(@“Task3”);
});

dispatch_async(myCustomQueue, ^ {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/) `dispatch_after`.
You can search its usage on stackoverflow.
Nice article is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1)

Brief example in Swift for 1.5 seconds delay:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 1.5)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     // your code here after 1.5 delay - pay attention it will be executed on the main thread
}
```

and objective-c:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    // your code here after 1.5 delay - pay attention it will be executed on the main thread
});
```

Comment: But how would you handle the delay in the last iteration of the loop? I need to delay before exiting the loop. I can't call dispatch_after, since there is no actual code block to execute after the last task in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ideal job for [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) with the delay being implemented like this:

```
@interface DelayOperation : NSOperation
@property (NSTimeInterval) delay;
- (void)main
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example that replicates the for loop in my sample code above?

Comment: @Oak You'll get that from reading the `NSOperationQueue` docs; you'll want to read them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a Swift version:

```
func delay(seconds seconds: Double, after: ()->()) {
    delay(seconds: seconds, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), after: after)
}

func delay(seconds seconds: Double, queue: dispatch_queue_t, after: ()->()) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, queue, after)
}
```

How you call it:

```
print("Something")    
delay(seconds: 2, after: { () -> () in
  print("Delayed print")    
})
print("Anotherthing")
```