# Add delay to a loop in android without stalling the UI Thread

Tags: java, android

I have been looking all over the Android Studio Docs and StackOverflow, but I can not seem to find a way to do the equivalent of what is done in IOS here:
[Adding Delay In A For Loop Without Blocking UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128624/adding-delay-in-a-for-loop-without-blocking-ui)
in Android.

I have tried to use a Handler, but instead of running the code like:

```
// Iteration 1
// Delay of 500ms
// Iteration 2
// Delay of 500ms
// ...
```

The code seems to be run as follows:

```
// Iteration 1
// Iteration 2
// Delay of 500ms
// next state
```

The code I am using is stuctured like this:

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
while (someCondition) {
    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            myFunction();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

The behavior I see when running this Activity is that is skips it, and after 500ms it goes to the next Activity (with expected result) but without showing the user what's happening.

How would I delay the loop so the user can see what's happening?

---

To clarivy:

The current state (after moveCard()) needs to be shown for x ms before going though the logic of my while loop again.

This is done untill the final state is has been reached.

Then the next Activity is started.

---

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.horserace_game);

    this.cardDeck = findViewById(R.id.deck);
    this.game_ended = false;

    this.deck = new Deck();
    this.aces = new ArrayList<>();
    this.acesPos = new ArrayList<>();
    this.hidden = new ArrayList<>();

    // Remove all Aces from deck and put them in aces
    //resetDeck creates a deck ordered on Face (so Ace SDHS, Two SDHS etc, which is handy for this purpose.
    this.deck.resetDeck(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        this.aces.add(this.deck.removeCard(0));
        // Add a new pos for card
        this.acesPos.add(0);
    }

    // Shuffle the deck
    this.deck.shuffleDeck();

    // Get 7 cards from the top of the deck to put on the
    // side of the track and place them face down on the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        this.hidden.add(this.deck.removeCard(0));
    }


    // Whilst the game is still running, pick a card from the deck and move the ace with the same suit
    while (!this.game_ended) {
        // Pick the next card from the deck
        this.next = this.deck.removeCard(0);
        cardDeck.setImageResource(getCardImage(next));
        // Find the ace with the same suit as this.next and set it's 'score'++
        for (Card ace : this.aces) {
            if (ace.getSuit().equals(next.getSuit())) {
                this.acesPos.set(ace.getSuit().ordinal(), this.acesPos.get(ace.getSuit().ordinal()) + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        // Final state: the last ace now has a pos >7, this ace is the result. start new Activity
        if (this.acesPos.get(next.getSuit().ordinal()) > 7) {
            this.game_ended = true;
            Intent winner = new Intent();
            winner.putExtra("winner",next.getSuit().ordinal());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, winner);
            finish();
        // If the ace is not at it's final position, move it 
        // and pick a new card in the next iteration.
        } else {
            // Move card
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("run: ", "moveCard");
                    moveCard();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: depends how you go to the next activity but it should happen after the myFunction() in the run() function

Comment: "How would I delay the loop so the user can see what's happening?" -- you do not have any code that represents "what's happening". You might want to expand your [mcve] to be the actual code that you are running. In general, having some sort of loop like this in `onCreate()` or similar methods is a doomed approach. Hopefully, a more representative [mcve] will give us the information to recommend an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks, I added an explenation on how I go to the next activity @Pearl

Comment: And thanks for you response @CommonsWare, I added my onCreate function too.

Comment: Consider going through my answer, I've used TimerTask and I think it should solve your problem.

Comment: Where did you get that code snippet @TirthMehta? I don't really get what's going on

Comment: @MarkBoute A TimerTask(java library) can be scheduled for one-time(or multiple times) by a Timer(which is executing in a new thread). Using the handler only probably stalls your main UI and hence you cannot really know whats going on it until the handler ends its execution which is why your user cannot see what is happening. The mHandler will execute your function once the timer calls run() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Creating Something like this should work,

```
protected static void startTimer() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
        }
    }, 500);
}

public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         myFunction();
    }
};
```

Comment: I am consufused what happen if the completion time of function more than 500ms

Answer (score 0):

moveCard() and wait to move to new intent:

```
            while (!this.game_ended) {
        // Pick the next card from the deck
        this.next = this.deck.removeCard(0);
        cardDeck.setImageResource(getCardImage(next));
        // Find the ace with the same suit as this.next and set it's 'score'++
        for (Card ace : this.aces) {
            if (ace.getSuit().equals(next.getSuit())) {
                this.acesPos.set(ace.getSuit().ordinal(), this.acesPos.get(ace.getSuit().ordinal()) + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        // Final state: the last ace now has a pos >7, this ace is the result. start new Activity
        if (this.acesPos.get(next.getSuit().ordinal()) > 7) {
            this.game_ended = true;
            myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   Intent winner = new Intent();
                    winner.putExtra("winner",next.getSuit().ordinal());

                    setResult(RESULT_OK, winner);
                    finish();
               }
            }, 500);
        // If the ace is not at it's final position, move it 
        // and pick a new card in the next iteration.
        } else {
            // Move card

                    Log.e("run: ", "moveCard");
                    moveCard();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I added additional comments, I am waiting for the final state, but what I am aiming for is a transition (no animation) between each moveCard(), so that the user can see the cards moving

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding, how do you know a final state is reached?  through a variable? a function?  If so you could just set a repeating timer checking that state or if its a function move to intent at the end of that function

Comment: this.acesPos.get(next.getSuit().ordinal()) > 7
this.acesPos is an ArrayList<Integer> with the current scores each Card ace has.
next.getSuit().ordinal() returns the index of the suit-type next has.
If the current pos is 8, so >7 then the final state is reached. @Pearl

Comment: oh, but you say your card could still be moving. I am not understand why you cannot just move the code I posted to the end of the move so when the last card is done moving it checks if the game is over and moves to next activity? Unless you have more than one card moving at once, then you would just need a counter that goes up when you call move card and goes down when its finished then you check if game is ended and count is 0

Comment: The card only moves if it's position is not >7, because when it is, it is the winner and therefor I start a new Activity showing that card.
Still all I need is logic -> moveCard() -> wait x ms -> continue logic.
wait x ms is just so the user can see the new position of the card @Pearl

Comment: Hmm seems like you should just wrap your next intent in the handler instead of the moveCard()  if you want to move the card then wait, right now you are waiting then moving card?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `Timer`, a polling model where the timer will run independently and execute the code in its associated `TimerTask` based on the frequency you define.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule (new TimerTask()
    {
     @Override public void run() 
     {
        // your program logic here
        if (game_ended)
          return;
        // Pick the next card from the deck
        next = deck.removeCard(0);
.
.
.
     }
    }, 0, 500);
```

This will start a timer immediately, with 500ms delay between triggers.  Each time the timer fires the `run()` method in TimerTask will execute.

Create the timer in `onCreate`, start/schedule it in `onResume`, stop in `onPause`.  Inside the TimerTask run() method you'd move your program logic.